# Google Maps API. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In our app, we use the google maps api(Javascript). Overall it works fine but from time to time it would stop to work because of what I believe is a change in the google maps api.

But I can't help to think that there is no way google is changing the behavior of the API like this overnight, so I must do something wrong.

Basically to get the center of the map I was doing:

```
map.getCenter().k+","+map.getCenter().B
```

But last night it was changed to

```
map.getCenter().k+","+map.getCenter().A
```

This must not be the right thing to do, because it's the third time they change the attribute.

Comment: What is it you are trying to get? Latitude / longitude?

Comment: **Do Not Use** the internal properties of the Google Maps Javascript API v2 (`map.getCenter().k`), use the documented properties (`map.getCenter().lat()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `getCenter()` actually returns `LatLng` object. And you are trying to get not documented properties from minimized obfuscated code. It will be changing each time google will minimize their code. You can't trust that variables. You should use `lat()` and `lng()` methods instead:

```
map.getCenter().lat()+","+map.getCenter().lng()
```

Read more on [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng)

Comment: Ah, here is the catch!